# How can I attach a Raspberry Pi Camera to my Pi for an image processing project?

Tags: pi-3, camera, raspicam

I want to attach a Raspberry Pi Camera to my Raspberry Pi module for an image processing project. Basically, I want to enhance video in the dark. I am planning to do a project in which the video footage gets enhanced through image processing but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3):

There's a camera setup guide at raspberrypi.org: [Getting started with picamera](http://http:/https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-picamera)

For low light you probably want to use a Noir (No infra red filter) camera or remove the filter from a standard pi camera.

To get started, there are loads of resources where people have used cameras for low light imaging, here's one: [Raspberry coulis](https://www.raspberrycoulis.co.uk/diy-hacks/raspberry-pi-night-vision-camera-hack/)

Have a go at a few :)